# jquery focus conflicts with android keyboard

Tags: android, jquery, android-webview

```
<input type="text" class="numberonly">
```

I want to change the type of this html input from text to number on focus.

```
$(".numberonly").focus(function(){
$(this).attr("type","number");
});
```

this jquery works fine but when the webpage is embedded inside the android webview, the android keyboard wont show up on focus. Does jquery **.focus** prevents default behavior or what? Should I trigger the focus programmaticaly?

e.g.

1. The second click in the input, brings up the keyboard.
2. The android default browser has no problem. But the webview inside the android app fails to load keyboard.